# Magento2: Argument 1 passed to Magento\InventorySalesAdminUi

Tags: magento2

I deleted all products directly from database:

```
delete from catalog_product_entity;
```

But now when I open `catalog-> products` then get issue:

```
Argument 1 passed to Magento\InventorySalesAdminUi\Model\GetSalableQuantityDataBySku::execute() must be of the type string, null given, called in /home/user/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/magento/module-inventory-sales-admin-ui/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/SalableQuantity.php on line 70
```

I try reset index, reidnex, deploy cf etc. but still no work. Any solution?

I have solved issue:

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity SET sku='' WHERE sku IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.  I had the same exact problem after updating magento from 1.9x to 2.4.2.  This solution worked for me as well.